# Get the data between two LMD in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table named

```
USER_BAG
```

in which I have this column

```
LAST_MODIFIED_DATE  DATE(7) NOT NULL
```

I need all the records whose `LAST_MODIFIED_DATE` falls between

`2012-08-20 16:13:19` and `2012-08-20 16:18:19`

I am using Oracle Database. Can anyone suggest me how can I achieve my scenario?

```
SELECT * FROM USER_BAG where LAST_MODIFIED_DATE between 
to_date ('2012-08-20 16:13:19', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') AND 
to_date ('2012-08-20 16:18:19', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss');
```

Anything wrong I am doing in the above sql query? I am working with Oracle. It always gives me-

```
[WARN]Execute Error : ORA-02392: exceeded session limit on CPU usage, you are being logged off (DBD ERROR: OCIStmtExecute)
[WARN]Fetch Error : ERROR no statement executing (perhaps you need to call execute first)

No Matches Found
```

**Update:-**

```
select * from user_resource_limits;

RESOURCE_NAME               LIMIT 
COMPOSITE_LIMIT             UNLIMITED 
SESSIONS_PER_USER           5 
CPU_PER_SESSION             100 
CPU_PER_CALL                UNLIMITED 
LOGICAL_READS_PER_SESSION   10000 
LOGICAL_READS_PER_CALL      UNLIMITED 
IDLE_TIME                   UNLIMITED 
CONNECT_TIME                15 
PRIVATE_SGA                 UNLIMITED
```

Comment: Is it really a table, or a view? How many records are there and how many do you expect the query to return? Is the column indexed? Do you have particularly low resouce limits in your user's profile (you can check in `user_resource_limits`)? Might be helpful to look at the explain plan to see if indexes - if present - are being used, if you can get direct access.

Comment: The action suggested for this error: "If this happens often, ask the database administrator to increase the CPU_PER_SESSION limit of the user profile."

Comment: I don't know how many records will it return and also column is not indexed. This is what I got(updated in the question) after querying `user_resource_limits` table. How can I use explain plan query to see whether the index has been created?

Comment: If there's no index then the explain plan can't show it being used, so there will be a full table scan; presumably the resources this requires are exceeding your limits. As APC and the error suggest, if you can't index the column (which might not solve the problem entirely anyway), talk to your DBA about increasing the limits in your profile.

Answer (score 1):

The CPU limit in your user profile is set too low. It only allows for 1 sec of CPU time per SQL execution.